# PHP cookie doesn't delete with class

Tags: php, cookies

I would like to know why I can't delete a cookie with a class but I can without any class.

**cookies.php**

```
static public function Delete($name, $expiry){
    unset($_COOKIE[$name]);
    setcookie($name, false, $expiry, '/');
}
```

**index.php**

```
if(Cookie::Exists('country')){
    Cookie::Delete($_COOKIE['country'], time() - 3600);
}
```

This doesn't work. The code below works.

```
if(Cookie::Exists('country')){
    setcookie('country', false, time() - 3600, '/');
}
```

I get no errors. I've made an `echo` of the content with both two options, the first one the `echo` always retrieve content..the second one it only retrieves content 1 time (after that is deleted..which is correct).

Comment: Have you tried: `Cookie::Delete('country', time() - 3600);`?

Comment: In first example you are passing cookie's value as parameter not the name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Cookie::Delete($_COOKIE['country'], time() - 3600);`

You are passing in the COOKIE's value as the name for your cookie. So if country was "UK" in the cookie, your DELETE method will set a cookie named "UK" to expire.

Change it too

`Cookie::Delete('country', time() - 3600);`